# Найти разность между показаниями за два соседних дня

Tags: plsql, sql

Необходимо найти разность между показаниями счетчиков за два соседних дня (sysdata-1) и (sysdata-2) 
Сами вычисляемые параметры являются составными. 
Например, (case when sum(rab1+rab2)!=0 then 100*sum(rab2+rab3)/sum(rab1+rab3) else 100 end) as RAB

То есть, из запроса

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN SUM(rab1+rab2)!=0 THEN 100*SUM(rab2+rab3)/SUM(rab1+rab3) ELSE 100 END) AS RAB
FROM
  tab1.tab t,
WHERE
   stat.DATETIME>=TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sysdate-1), 'dd.mm.yyyy') || '00:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

нужно вычесть запрос

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN SUM(rab1+rab2)!=0 THEN 100*SUM(rab2+rab3)/SUM(rab1+rab3) ELSE 100 END) AS RAB
FROM
  tab1.tab t,
WHERE
   stat.DATETIME>=TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sysdate-2), 'dd.mm.yyyy') || '00:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

Так, чтобы результат был записан одной строкой.

Answer (score 1):

Раз уж мы заговорили о PL/SQL, предлагаю следующую реализацию. Будем использовать функцию для получения однотипного запроса. Я не понял ваших манипуляций с таблицами и алиасами, а также условием `datetime`, но идея следующая.

```
declare
        day_1_rab number; -- значение за одну дату
        day_2_rab number; -- значение за другую
        delta number; -- разность значений

        function get_rab(p_date in date) return number
        is
            ret number;
        begin
            select
                case
                    when sum(rab1 + rab2) != 0
                    then 100 * sum(rab2 + rab3) / sum(rab1 + rab3)
                else 100
                end
            into ret
            from tab1.tab t
            where t.DATETIME >= p_date
            ;
            return ret;
        end;
begin
        day_1_rab := get_rab(trunc(sysdate-1));
        day_2_rab := get_rab(trunc(sysdate-2));
        delta := day_1_rab - day_2_rab;
        -- здесь нужно вывести значение (например, с помощью dbms_output)
        dbms_output.put_line('Разность оставляет: '||to_char(delta, '999G990D00'));
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

С Ораклом не работаю, но можно попробовать тупо:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN SUM(rab1+rab2)!=0 THEN 100*SUM(rab2+rab3)/SUM(rab1+rab3) ELSE 100 END
-(SELECT 
CASE WHEN SUM(rab1+rab2)!=0 THEN 100*SUM(rab2+rab3)/SUM(rab1+rab3) ELSE 100 END AS RAB
FROM
  tab1.tab t,
WHERE
   stat.DATETIME>=TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sysdate-2), 'dd.mm.yyyy') || '00:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
) 
AS RAB
FROM
  tab1.tab t,
WHERE
   stat.DATETIME>=TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sysdate-1), 'dd.mm.yyyy') || '00:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

Comment: К сожалению, не работает

Comment: А что говорит-то?
Мне не на чем проверить.

Comment: А такие задачи обязательно решать чисто sql'ем?

Comment: Мне обязательно решить ее именно в pl/sql. Иначе я обошелся бы Excel ))

Comment: Ничего не говорит. Не работает.

Comment: Используйте pl/sql-курсор, или это недопустимо?

Answer (score 0):

Методом копипаста, могу ошибиться в скобках.

```
SELECT  
((CASE WHEN stat.DATETIME>=TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sysdate-1), 'dd.mm.yyyy') || '00:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') THEN
CASE WHEN SUM(rab1+rab2)!=0 THEN 100*SUM(rab2+rab3)/SUM(rab1+rab3) ELSE 100 END
ELSE 0 END) -
(CASE WHEN stat.DATETIME>=TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sysdate-2), 'dd.mm.yyyy') || '00:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') THEN
CASE WHEN SUM(rab1+rab2)!=0 THEN 100*SUM(rab2+rab3)/SUM(rab1+rab3) ELSE 100 END
ELSE 0 END)) AS RAB
FROM 
  tab1.tab t 
WHERE 
   stat.DATETIME>=TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sysdate-2), 'dd.mm.yyyy') || '00:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое:

```
select
(SELECT 
CASE WHEN SUM(rab1+rab2)!=0 THEN 100*SUM(rab2+rab3)/SUM(rab1+rab3) ELSE 100 END) AS RAB
FROM
  tab1.tab t,
WHERE
   stat.DATETIME>=TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sysdate-1), 'dd.mm.yyyy') || '00:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) - 
(SELECT 
CASE WHEN SUM(rab1+rab2)!=0 THEN 100*SUM(rab2+rab3)/SUM(rab1+rab3) ELSE 100 END) AS RAB
FROM
  tab1.tab t,
WHERE
   stat.DATETIME>=TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sysdate-2), 'dd.mm.yyyy') || '00:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) as res_sum
from dual
```